# In SQL Server, how to configure Fulltext Search to index 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have created substitution thesaurus entries for the following:

```
Pair: 1/2, half
Pair: 1/3, third
Pair: 1/4, quarter
Pair: 1/8, eighth
```

When I do a search with a search term such as, "1/2 inch pipe" I should get back rows that contain "1/2" as well as "half".  I have two such rows.  However, with default full-text search out of the box, it seems that "1/2" is not included in the results of the full-text indexing on the column in question.

I have not yet found a definitive answer as to what, where, how to configure a re-indexing of the full-text columns such that the full-text search criteria includes allowing 1/2, 1/3, etc.  For that matter, I also need single numbers in the full-text search.

If someone could guide me to some documentation that covers the steps by which I can accomplish this task, I would greatly appreciate  it.

Comment: Only a comment. The rules for what is a word is not clear. Stopword can be used to eliminate. It appears a single number is not considered a word and / is treated as a word break. I hope you get an answer. Not sure how much control Lucene has but something to consider.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "When I do a search with a search term such as, "1/2 inch pipe" I should get back rows that contain "1/2" as well as "half""! Do you want Fulltext to interpret "1/2" and "half" as equivalent representations?

Comment: Yes, @aks, I want Fulltext to interpret what I might nickname, "visual equivalent" pairs such as my example of 1/2 and half.  The reason for this is simply that the textual content with which I am doing Fulltext searching contains common vernacular phrases, such as, "Steel pipe, 1/2-inch diameter."  In this case, when someone searches using a query containing the search phrase, "half-inch pipe," the results should include that "Steel pipe, 1/2-inch diameter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sys.dm_fts_parser is a great DMF to get an idea of how Fulltext is parsing the sentence and what words are going to be stored in the internal index. For your first example I see the following output -

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(N'"Pair: 1/2, half"', 1033, 0, 0)

keyword group_id    phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term
0x0070006100690072     1    0   1   Exact Match pair    0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x0031                 1    0   2   Noise Word  1       0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x006E006E0031         1    0   2   Noise Word  nn1     0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x0032                 1    0   3   Noise Word  2       0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x006E006E0032         1    0   3   Noise Word  nn2     0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x00680061006C0066     1    0   4   Exact Match half    0   Pair: 1/2, half
```

FT breaks up "1/2" and indexes it as 1, nn1, 2 and nn2('nn' is an internal representation for numeric values). In this case, the default stoplist is being used which additionally results in these values being tagged as noise words, hence they are not added to the index. Circumventing that is simple by either removing the entries from the stoplist or creating a new blank stoplist and associating that with the index.

As of now there simply isn't any way of getting FT to ignore the '/' symbol which it is treating as a word separator in this case.

**EDIT** - Apparently, there is a workaround, and it involves creating a custom dictionary as [detailed here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263242.aspx). So, for the English language, I created a 'Custom0009.lex' file in the Binn directory and added an entry for '/'. Doing so shows the following output of sys.dm_fts_parser(don't forget to restart fdhost) -

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(N'"Pair: 1/2, half"', 1033, NULL, 0)

keyword             group_id    phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term
0x0070006100690072  1   0   1   Exact Match pair    0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x0031              1   0   2   Exact Match 1       0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x006E006E0031      1   0   2   Exact Match nn1     0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x002F              1   0   3   Exact Match /       0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x0032              1   0   4   Exact Match 2       0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x006E006E0032      1   0   4   Exact Match nn2     0   Pair: 1/2, half
0x00680061006C0066  1   0   5   Exact Match half    0   Pair: 1/2, half
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that "/" character is not supported in full text search.
I would suggest the use of LIKE, although slower.

Comment: The use of `like` is not an option in my case.

Comment: Surely other people are using data that contains fractions in the form of 1/2, etc., in full-text indexing.